# いいことですね vs. いいですね

Tags: grammar, nuances, set-phrases, conversations, conversational

Is there a difference between these two responses?

> **いいことですね。** and
>
> **いいですね。**

---

Examples:

> A: 日本語のために、毎日日本語のラジオを聞いています。
>
> B: 勉強のためですか。**いいことですね**。
>
> ---
>
> A: 週末は大阪に行くんです。
>
> B: そうですか。それは**いいですね**。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to say ***yes***, there is a difference.  The difference here is not so small, I might add.

In the first example, 「いいことですね」 means "***It's a good thing to do***.  What it is really saying is "***You have formed a good habit***."

In the second example, 「いいですね」 means "***How nice!***", "***Awesome!***", "***That's cool!***", etc.